# Problem with question view count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, private-beta

I guess there's a problem with the view counts of questions. One of my questions do have an answer, but the view count is 0. Shouldn't it be at least 1?

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43751/a-bug-in-the-views-calculation-views-0-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure it's a caching issue. The caching has a much more exaggerated effect when traffic gets very low. With it being a holiday weekend in the US and the very limited test audience to begin with, I imagine the overall traffic was very low. I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: Is there caching when you access the API ? If not this could be a good way to check if view count is really OK.